# How to convert an anonymously typed List to List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, anonymous-types

This simple Linq query:

```
from c in mycontext.Customers
join o in mycontext.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
where o.Status == 1
select new {c, o}
```

will result in

```
List<{c:Customer, o:Order}>
```

after calling `ToList()`.

What's the easiest way of converting this anonymously typed list into a list of customers (`List<Customer>`)?

EDIT: I need the orders for an extra condition, I've changed my original question.

Comment: Do you need the Orders at all or? if not you could just "select c" instead of "select new {c, o}"

Comment: Why are you joining on Orders, if you only need customers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
result.Select(o => o.Customer).ToList();
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: This would return each customer `X` times, where `X` is the number of orders associated to each customer. Your answer is not wrong but maybe he wanted the distinct customers, and he better know this example doesn't do it.

Comment: Good point. The question is why is there the join with Orders?  
Anyway you can still call .Distinct() if necessary...

Comment: this isn't the simplest way though

Answer (score 1):

very basic approach, as you explecitely asked "What's the easiest way of converting **this** anonymously typed [...]":

```
var anonymousEnumerable = from c in mycontext.Customers
                          join o in mycontext.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
                          select new
                          {
                              c,
                              o
                          };
var typedEnumerable = anonymousList.Select(item => item.c).Distinct(); // either referenceCheck or you supply an IEqualityComparer<Customer>-implementation
```

maybe you can give us some more information an what you want exactly to achieve!

Comment: I want to convert the result of my Linq query into a List<Customer> as simply as possible.

Comment: for **this** list, i gave you the answer ... if you'd like a more general (aka generic) answer, there might be another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

why not just use `.ToList<Customers>()`

and don't select the orders - you don't need them after the join.

```
List<Customer> custList =  (from c in mycontext.Customers
    join o in mycontext.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
    where o.Status == 1
    select c).ToList<Customer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need both the properties? If so step through the list and instantiate each curstomer...

Something like

```
 List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
 foreach(item in linqQuery.ToList())
 {

     customers.Add(item.c);
     //do something with the Order here...
 }
```

Comment: You don't need the `.ToList()`. Actually you wouldn't need 4 lines to do it, but it's a matter of choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ledger = from c in mycontext.Customers
                 join o in mycontext.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
                 where o.Status == 1
                 select new {c, o};

var customers = (from row in ledger select row.Customer).Distinct().ToList();
```

That would be my sorta bidding on a solution (inclusive mispellings etc.) :)